# Need Xquery functionality of fn:replace for use with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, xquery

I am looking for the functionality of the Xquery function [fn:replace](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_replace.html) for use with PostgreSQL. Here is the specific XQuery code that needs to be implemented in PostgreSQL:

```
declare function local:canonical($n as xs:string?) as xs:string? {
  replace(fn:lower-case($n),'[^0-9a-z]','')
  };
```

The intent is to convert upper to lower case and keep only letters and digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `regexp_replace` is what you're looking for:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: There is a fourth argument, flags, that I have not found documentation for but an example shows a value of 'g' (assumed to be global) that addresses the part I was missing.

Comment: @C.W.HolemanII I'm not familiar with the `g` flag, but I assume Postgres's regex flags would be similar to XPath: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#flags.